# Rails Admin Home Button Messing up with my main page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have tried looking for an answer online regarding this but I can't seem to find any solution.
I am using the rails_admin gem in my rails application. Everything seems to work fine but when I click the Home button in the Admin Workspace portal it messes up with the layout of my application, for which I have to refresh the page to get it back to normal. Would really appreciate help on this. Please check the images.

[image: Screen 1] [image: Home Button] [image: Layout Error]

Comment: It looks to me like the home request is being performed as an AJAX request and pushing the result into the DOM in a strange place. Do you have control over the home link? Maybe ensure it doesn't have `data-remote=true` or that it is definitely making an HTML request.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response... I am using rails_admin gem: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin. I don't really have control over the home button (I think so). One thing to note is that if I refresh the admin page and then click on the home button then it's working perfectly fine - but if I click directly onto the home button without that it does what is shown above

Comment: Hi, I still have not been able to figure it out... Any help?